# Can you undo 'git reset --hard HEAD' if never having made a commit?

Tags: git, version-control, commit, reset

I lost some code after running

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

and I never committed the work. Is there any way to get this code back? Was it logged anywhere? Can I undo the command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, `git reset --hard` and `git checkout -f` are both destructive of changes that haven't been committed.

Answer (score 0):

Any uncommitted changes in your working directory ( including staged ) will be lost. That is why you should use it cautiously ( or use other flags like `--mixed`, `--soft`)